# Wordpress Slick Slider + Magnific Popup

Tags: php, jquery

just wondering if I can get the cropped image and also the original of cropped image. Using ACF to build a slider that images are in light box !

```
 <div class="slide">
    <a href="<?php echo image1_full-sized-image ?>" class="mfp-image">
        <img src="<?php echo image1_cropped-image?>"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

- My goal is to cropped images and show them in slider but use the original images in light box !

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get original image and a smaller version of it. Use `wp_get_attachment_url($id)` to get the full url and `wp_get_attachment_image_src($id,$size)` for the smaller version.

**EDIT:** You can get the name of the original uncropped (full) image from the attachments post_meta. Then replace the cropped file name with the original name in the full url. *If there's more direct way to do this, I'm all ears.*

For example like this,

```
$image_id = 0; // get this from the saved ACF data
$full_image = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id );
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'thumbnail' ); // or some other valid image size

// get original file name and replace cropped name with it
$backup_full = get_post_meta( $image_id, '_wp_attachment_backup_sizes', true );
if ( ! empty( $backup_full['full-orig']['file'] ) ) {
    $full_path = explode( '/', $full_image );
    $full_image = str_replace( end( $full_path ), $backup_full['full-orig']['file'], $full_image );
}

if ( $full_image && is_array( $thumbnail ) ) {
  printf(
    '<div class="slide">
        <a href="%s" class="mfp-image">
            <img src="%s"/>
        </a>
    </div>',
    esc_url( $full_image ),
    esc_url( $thumbnail[0] )
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! 
Well yes this is working if you get the defined size's as thumbnail, small or large or any other defined. But I want to use cropping tool so each image size can be different from another one !
if I upload and image and crop it free as I want it get's a prefix as image1-e1566822150490.jpg. And know I want to get this image and also the original image as image1.jpg. Any idea for this ?

Comment: @GMedija I don't think there's any direct way to get the original uncropped file name. I added one way to get it to my code example. The original file name is saved as post_meta for the attachment, which you can get with `get_post_meta()`. In my example I just did simple string replacement to get the original file name to the full image url.

Comment: well, thanks for you time !

Comment: @GMedija If my answer solved your question, you can mark it as accepted, thanks!